# Opposite of the suffix -less

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, suffixes

I'm looking for a suffix that has the opposite meaning of the suffix *-less* as in *stainless*. That is, a suffix that means “not free of ...”. In German, for example, there is the adverb “*behaftet*” and one can say “*fehlerbehaftet*” (meaning “not free of defects”).

In particular, I'm looking for opposites of *unitless* and [*dimensionless*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity) (w.r.t. physical quantities).

Comment: _-ful_ would normally be the opposite, I guess (as in hopeful <> hopeless) ; but it doesn't always work. _Dimensioned_ comes to mind, but for _with units_ I hope someone will provide an answer for you :)

Comment: Some words that cannot use *less* as a suffix may be able to use *-free*, usually as a hyphenated compound word or phrase. However they sometimes coexist as *carefree* and *careless*, meaning very different things.

Comment: "stained and "defective", but that doesn't seem to imply "united" or "dimensioned"....

Comment: In practical scientific usage I *think* the opposites are "having a unit" or "having units", and "having a dimension" or "having dimension" or "having dimensions". For example, "α is dimensionless quantity, G is a quantity having dimensions". Or just, "G has dimensions" of course (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=having+dimension%2C+has+dimensions&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chaving%20dimension%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20dimensions%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no universal affix in English equivalent to the German suffix *behaftet.*

Instead, there are two different ways to form this kind of adjective in English.

- The suffix *-ful* suggests that the noun modified has the quality in question in abundance. It is a limited suffix that can be used only with certain words: hopeful, but not hungerful.
- The past participle of some verbs can also be used as an adjective. For example, the opposite of "stainless" is "stained." Again, this does not work with all verbs, and I'm not sure what the rule is. It seems to be more common with transitive verbs ("stained," "baked") but also includes some intransitive verbs ("fallen," "wilted"). It cannot be used with nouns, but is often used with words that share a noun and verb--all four of the examples above fall into this category, and it may in fact be a requirement.

Your specific examples don't fall into either category. They're both nouns, so the verb tense trick doesn't work. ("Dimensioned" is a word but suggests "having been dimensioned" rather than "having a dimension.") And neither is on the *-ful* list.

So you have to use a multi-word construction instead of a suffix. This is pretty common in translating from German, which, from a native English speaker's perspective, seems to have an affix for just about everything.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Do you have suggestions for multi-word opposites for "unitless" and "dimensionless"?

Comment: As @bib suggests, "dimensional" and "unitized" are antonyms of "dimensionless" and "unitless," respectively.

Comment: *For example, the opposite of "stainless" is "stained."* Hmm, doesn't stainless (as in "stainless steel") mean "doesn't stain", rather than "doesn't currently have any stains"? For the latter meaning, I'd use stain-*free*, not stainless.

Comment: Try _-able_. I differentiate between "stainless" and "unstained" (and would choose "stainable" and "stained" as the opposites, respectively).

Comment: @starsplusplus - That's what I was thinking as well, when using it as an adjective to describe a property.

Comment: I think you mean "past participle", not "past tense" of the verb (that would be "fell", not "fallen", though for most verbs it is the same).

Comment: Yes, you're right; it's the participle, not the simple past.

Comment: _unitized_ would say to me: "comes in one piece, not of separate parts". http://mymathforum.com/algebra/3952-what-opposite-unitless.html and http://www.studyguidenow.com/2244346/What-Is-The-Opposite-Of-Unitless%3F seem to say there is no good way to say this. Maybe just say nothing, and imply that there are units?

Comment: _"It is a limited suffix that can be used only with certain words: hopeful, but not hungerful."_ The same goes for the suffix in the question as it was asked: hopeless but hungerless.

Answer (score 10):

Without commenting on the more general forming of anti *-less* terms, you could consider **unitized** and **dimensional**.

Comment: Thanks for your input! A shame that one can accept only one answer.

Comment: I agree that @chapka has the more complete answer and I voted for it too.

Comment: *Dimensional*, why not, it's about right. But *unitized*? The verb *unitize* doesn't mean “put a unit to a number”, and I'm not sure if I'd understand it without very explicit context. Have you seen this usage in the wild?

Comment: @Gilles *Unitize* means to form into a single unit or into multiple units. Buld material can be *unitized*, packaged, and the material is then not *unitless*. Exactly what OP is seeking, I do not know.

Comment: In this context, we're talking about physical quantities. A [dimensionless quantity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity) is a number which has no unit (e.g. a ratio between two lengths) or which has a dimensionless unit (e.g. an angle). The word *dimensionless* is used commonly in physics, *unitless* markedly less so but is comprehensible without blinking (it just means “with no unit”, where the meaning of *unit* is obviously-in-context kg, meter, etc. and has nothing to do with e.g. packaging units).

Comment: I've only ever seen "dimensional" used on its own to refer to lumber ("dimensional" lumber is cut to standard dimensions--not exactly the meaning the OP is looking for, but I agree, pretty close). Is it used in other contexts?

Comment: @chapka See [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/dimensional) for examples

Comment: Yes, but most of those examples aren't of "dimensional" used alone; they're words like "one-dimensional" or "three-dimensional," which to me constitute a special case. Then there's one technical term used in testing and one reference to lumber.

Answer (score 6):

The *-ful* suffix can frequently be used to form the opposite of an adjective ending in  *-less*.

Another general translation of the *behaftet* concept might be ***-bearing***.  That would be appended to form a hyphenated word, e.g. a *fruit-bearing* tree.  Note that a fruit-bearing tree is not quite the same as a fruitful tree.  The former emphasizes the general behaviour of the species, while the latter emphasizes the productivity of one particular tree.  (In German, *fruchttragend* and *fruchtbar*, respectively.)

As another example, the opposite of being *blameless* is to *bear blame*.  It could be expressed as a hyphenated adjective *blame-bearing*, but in practice, such usage is rare in English.

A ***unit-bearing number*** would be a good way to express the opposite of a dimensionless quantity, and in my opinion, easier to understand than "dimensioned", "dimensional", or "unitized".  That said, I have difficulty finding examples of such usage in the wild… here's [one](http://www.resoo.org/docs/perl/perl_tutorial/lesson16.html).

---

To translate *fehlerbehaftet*, I'd simply say *defective*, *faulty*, or *imperfect*.  Since those simple expressions exist, anything else would be awkward.

Comment: I do like "-bearing". In the case of "unit-bearing", however, there [might be some room for confusion](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=unit-bearing&client=ubuntu&hs=a2O&hl=en&channel=fs&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=1ctQU8KnPMmI7Aav34GoDw&ved=0CDIQ7Ak&biw=1172&bih=959).

Comment: There's no confusion, especially for a hyphenated adjective. You're just taking the term out of context.

Answer (score 5):

The above answers are indicative of existing usage and contain a lot of good ideas.  However, here's another one.

Especially in technical jargon, people invent words like "unitful" or "dimensionful" and they often stick.  For example, "stateless objects" in object-oriented software design are objects that don't carry state between method calls.  "Stateful objects", meaning "objects that are not stateless" are objects that do carry state between method calls.  These words were invented back in the 90's, and they caught on because they are a concise, intuitive, and accurate way of describing the phenomena to which they allude.

So, if perhaps you were writing an article  about "unitless somethingorothers", you might state that you were going to use the term "unitful" to mean the opposite of "unitless" in the paper.  If it's a useful enough word (and it seems pretty clear that its meaning is easily grasped intuitively, difficult to mistake, and more economical than most of the alternatives), it could very well catch on.  So why not?  Shakespeare did it.  :)

Comment: As an aside, I often use "-ful" as a sort of joke.  But anyone who hears me refer to a "wireful controller" to my XBox (as I have) knows what I mean without further comment.

Comment: An example of this would be RESTful and RESTless for web services that respect REST (Representational State Transfer) which basically means using HTTP as it was meant to be used. There is room in English for more words.

Comment: Yes, that's another good example, although acronyms that become words is another wrinkle in the subject.  ("Self-contained underwater breathing apparatus" comes to mind.)

Comment: I wouldn't use _-ful_ unless I know my audience is familiar with such terms and uses them all the time. In other words, they should be standard nomenclature and not something you just made up.

Comment: @PhilPerry: Yes, that's certainly a POV with many adherents. Shakespeare wouldn't be one of them, of course, and Lewis Carroll would simply "chortle" at the idea. :)  For my part, I will simply reiterate that any audience of XBox users would understand the words "wireful controller" without ever having heard them before, and would probably snicker upon hearing them.

Answer (score 4):

And I would consider **dimensioned** as an antonym of "dimensionless."  In that I disagree with the learned @chapka.

Answer (score 4):

Consider "fraught" as another suffix antonymic to "less."

> [It is a nettlesome, guilt-fraught topic](http://www.nytimes.com/1981/02/15/nyregion/surviving-a-guilt-trip-in-the-city.html).

Answer (score 3):

As well as the previously-mentioned hyphenated affix ***-bearing***, consider also the possibilities ***iferous*** (e.g. *carboniferous, odoriferous*), ***-laden*** (e.g. *guilt-laden, dust-laden, bin-laden*) and ***-carrying*** (e.g. *load-carrying, knife-carrying*).

These won't work universally, but may be useful now and again.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience reading and writing in nuclear and particle physics, **dimensionful** is the clearest and most common antonym for dimensionless.  Some quick searching reveals [many examples from the arxiv](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dimensionful+site%3Aarxiv.org), such as [this recent abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.7030) which explicitly uses "dimensionless and dimensionful" as antonyms.

Comment: Just Googling, *dimensionful* seems to be used mainly by particle physicists. I suspect most scientists in other disciplines will be baffled by this word.

Comment: Edited --- perhaps my experience is more parochial than I'd thought. Though in my defense, lots of good words have come out of physics :)

Answer (score 1):

The suffix *[-some](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-some&searchmode=none)*, like previously-mentioned *[-ful](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-ful&searchmode=none)*, has an applicable sense. From [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-some&searchmode=none):

> **-some (1)**
>       word-forming element used in making adjectives from nouns or adjectives (and sometimes verbs) and meaning "tending to; causing; to a considerable degree," from Old English *-sum*, identical with *som* (see *some*).

Words with this kind of *-some* suffix include *[handsome](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=handsome&searchmode=none)*, *[winsome](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=winsome&searchmode=none)*, *[toothsome](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=toothsome&searchmode=none)*, *[wearisome](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=wearisome&searchmode=none)*, etc.  (Words with the other two *-some* senses that etymonline.com shows include *[twosome](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twosome)* for sense (2),  “suffix added to numerals meaning "a group of (that number),"” and *[ribosome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosome)* for sense (3), “word-forming element meaning "the body," Modern Latin, from Greek soma "the body"”.)

For the latter part of your question – opposites of *unitless* and *dimensionless* –  note that *[dimensional](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dimensional)* has among its senses “Having dimension or dimensions”, and the word has been [frequently used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dimensional+analysis&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdimensional%20analysis%3B%2Cc0) in the phrase *dimensional analysis*, which refers to the process of analyzing dimensional units of quantities.  But dimensional analysis works with unitless quantities as well as dimensioned quantities, so *dimensional* is not quite satisfactory as an antonym for *dimensionless*.

*[Dimensionful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dimensionful)* (“(mathematics) Possessing dimension
”), on the other hand, while it sounds like a neologism and *[dimensioned](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dimensioned)* seems to me more appropriate, is nevertheless in [regular use](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dimensionful%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) as an antonym; eg:

> In such a case, we know that the ordinary Klein-Gordon action does not require any **dimensionful** prefactor, for J d²cr(daÛ)² is indeed **dimensionless** when the Klein-Gordon field Û is itself dimensionless.

[In the quote, I substituted Û for X-hat]